# during the download i get E/CursorWindow

Tags: android

my application is downloading large files from internet. but during the download i get 
 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
error. I am using download manager.

I get a very long out put part it looks like:

```
Cursor finalized without prior close()
Cursor finalized without prior close()
Cursor finalized without prior close()
Cursor finalized without prior close()
Cursor finalized without prior close()
Cursor finalized without prior close()
Cursor finalized without prior close()



 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
 E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.


09-01 23:08:44.241  17397-17615/com.yasna.appsaraai W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-01 23:08:44.246  16969-17654/? E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
09-01 23:08:44.246  16969-17654/? E/JavaBinder﹕ *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=552 (# cursors opened by this proc=4) (# cursors opened by pid 17397=548)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:109)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:100)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:301)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
            at android.database.CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor.getBulkCursorDescriptor(CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor.java:148)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:118)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-01 23:08:44.251  17397-17615/com.yasna.appsaraai W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 23:08:44.251  17397-17615/com.yasna.appsaraai W/System.err﹕ at af.yasna.appsaraai.ApkFileDownloader$1.run(ApkFileDownloader.java:105)
09-01 23:08:44.251  17397-17615/com.yasna.appsaraai W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-01 23:08:44.256  16969-17642/? E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
09-01 23:08:44.256  16969-17642/? E/JavaBinder﹕ *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=552 (# cursors opened by this proc=4) (# cursors opened by pid 17397=548)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:109)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:100)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:301)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
            at android.database.CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor.getBulkCursorDescriptor(CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor.java:148)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:118)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the whole stack trace

Comment: something is wrong as: "Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=552 (# cursors opened by this proc=4) (# cursors opened by pid 17397=548)"